# SQL Server DENSE_RANK()

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands, dense-rank, partition-by

I have a table where each line item contains a unit#, date stamp, and bed count. A record is created each day for each unit with the number of beds.

```
Unit   DateTime    Beds
----------------------
ICU    2011-03-23  12
ICU    2011-03-24  24
ICU    2011-03-25  24
ICU    2011-03-26  35
ICU    2011-03-27  24
ICU    2011-03-28  24
```

I am attempting to take the data and create a table like the one below.

```
Unit Beds  StartDate  EndDate
------------------------------
ICU  12    2011-03-23 2011-03-23
ICU  24    2011-03-24 2011-03-25
ICU  35    2011-03-26 2011-03-26
ICU  24    2011-03-27 2011-03-28
```

The issue is that the rows with 24 beds are being combined to get these results.

```
Unit Beds  StartDate  EndDate
------------------------------
ICU  12    2011-03-23 2011-03-23
ICU  24    2011-03-24 2011-03-28
ICU  35    2011-03-26 2011-03-26
```

I tried using DENSE_RANK to assign a ranking to use as a grouping number to separate the instances of the 24 beds. I want to the grouper values to be 1,2,2,3,4,4. Instead the grouper values are 1,2,2,3,2,2.

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Unit ORDER BY Beds) AS Grouper, 
Unit, DateTime, Beds
FROM StatsLocation 

Grouper Unit DateTime    Beds
-------------------------------
1       ICU  2011-03-23  12
2       ICU  2011-03-24  24
2       ICU  2011-03-25  24
3       ICU  2011-03-26  35
2       ICU  2011-03-27  24
2       ICU  2011-03-28  24
```

Comment: You may be interested in [*this answer to, "Solving “Gaps and Islands” with row_number() and dense_rank()?*](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167069/2639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag` to check if the previous row has the same value for beds and get the running sum as Grouper column.

```
SELECT SUM(COL) OVER(PARTITION BY Unit ORDER BY DateTime) as Grouper,Unit,DateTime,Beds
FROM (
SELECT CASE WHEN lag(beds) OVER(PARTITION BY Unit ORDER BY DateTime)=beds then 0 ELSE 1 END AS col, 
Unit, DateTime, Beds
FROM StatsLocation
) X
```

Thereafter, to get the start and end dates is easy with min and max for each group.

```
WITH CTE AS( 
SELECT SUM(COL) OVER(PARTITION BY Unit ORDER BY DateTime) as Grouper,Unit,DateTime,Beds
FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN lag(beds) OVER(PARTITION BY Unit ORDER BY DateTime)=beds then 0 ELSE 1 END AS col, 
      Unit, DateTime, Beds
      FROM StatsLocation) t
)
SELECT UNIT,BEDS,MIN(DATETIME) AS STARTDATE,MAX(DATETIME) AS ENDDATE
FROM CTE
GROUP BY UNIT,BEDS,GROUPER
```

If you don't need a grouper column,but just the start and end dates, this can be done with difference of row numbers.

```
SELECT UNIT,BEDS,MIN(DATETIME) AS STARTDATE,MAX(DATETIME) AS ENDDATE
FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Unit ORDER BY Dt)
   - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Unit,Beds ORDER BY Dt) AS    Grouper, 
Unit, Dt, Beds
FROM StatsLocation) T
GROUP BY UNIT,BEDS,GROUPER
```

Comment: The last one worked! Thank you! I fiddled around with RANK, DENSE_RANK, and ROW_NUMBER for quite awhile.

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem, you can solve it using two `row_number()`s like so:

```
select 
    Unit
  , Beds
  , StartDate = min(DateTime)
  , EndDate   = max(DateTime)
from (
  select *
    , rn_x = row_number() over (partition by unit order by [datetime]) 
    , rn_y = row_number() over (partition by unit, beds order by [datetime]) 
  from t 
    ) as s
group by Unit, Beds, rn_x-rn_y
order by Unit, StartDate
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/IJXC7931

returns:

```
+------+------+------------+------------+
| Unit | Beds | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+------+------+------------+------------+
| ICU  |   12 | 2011-03-23 | 2011-03-23 |
| ICU  |   24 | 2011-03-24 | 2011-03-25 |
| ICU  |   35 | 2011-03-26 | 2011-03-26 |
| ICU  |   24 | 2011-03-27 | 2011-03-28 |
+------+------+------------+------------+
```